# Consuming a web service in a Visual C++ 2008 DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, web-services

I need to call a third party Web Service from within a VC++ 2008 DLL.
The DLL is using MFC in a Shared DLL and it is not using ATL.
In solution explorer the Add Web Reference item is grayed.

any suggestion?

thank you in advance

stefano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since calling a WS in C# is trivial, first create a dll in C# wrapping the service call and expose it via COM interop to your C++ code. Even if it seems tricky is the less troubles way to go.